# Create a responsive row

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am really so confused that I could scream. I am trying to get out of my bootstrap happit, and learn to use my own breakpoints. I am looking at this page:

http://zurb.com/studios

which I like a lot. I am trying to understand the code. Under each row the fx call class large-12 columns. Where is those defined? I would just like to learn how to make a grid like that website. Maybe somebody knows a tutorial somewhere?

Comment: you could use responsive grids, this page give you all the code when you select how many columns http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/calculator/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the bootstrap css you can see the code that they used to make this simple yet very effective grid system considering the page can only be so wide you can limit how wide the width is just using some simple css -- Here is the code.

```
.col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
  }
```

^ this is used to keep them all to the left.
Below is what you are more interested in though.

```
  .col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-7 {
    width: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%;
  }
```

Below you might not be as interested in but it displays some other stuff along the grid system.

```
  .col-md-pull-12 {
    right: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-11 {
    right: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-10 {
    right: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-9 {
    right: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-8 {
    right: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-7 {
    right: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-6 {
    right: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-5 {
    right: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-4 {
    right: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-3 {
    right: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-2 {
    right: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-1 {
    right: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-0 {
    right: auto;
  }
  .col-md-push-12 {
    left: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-push-11 {
    left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-push-10 {
    left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-push-9 {
    left: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-push-8 {
    left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-push-7 {
    left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-push-6 {
    left: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-push-5 {
    left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-push-4 {
    left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-push-3 {
    left: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-push-2 {
    left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-push-1 {
    left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-push-0 {
    left: auto;
  }
  .col-md-offset-12 {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-11 {
    margin-left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-10 {
    margin-left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-9 {
    margin-left: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-8 {
    margin-left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-7 {
    margin-left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-6 {
    margin-left: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-5 {
    margin-left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-4 {
    margin-left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-3 {
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-2 {
    margin-left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-1 {
    margin-left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-0 {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
```